# Overhead of using 'new' to create object in dynamic ram vs automatic to create on stack

Tags: c++

Let's suppose I have a class named `Foo`, and `sizeof(Foo)` is 10 bytes.

As I understand it, creating a Foo with 'automatic' scope (on the stack) has zero overhead. If the Object occupies 10 bytes, it consumes 10 bytes on the stack. Period.

I'm kind of fuzzy about how creating objects with 'new' works on an 8-bit AVR. I know that 'new' ultimately calls malloc(), and that on Windows/Linux, malloc() ultimately asks the operating system for memory whose management is up to the OS itself. But... with 8-bit AVR, there *is no* operating system. So, presumably, something else has ultimate responsibility for managing its heap. And presumably, there's some kind of overhead involved so it can keep track of which bytes have been returned to it by a destructor, and which ones are still in use.

So... using the hypothetical 10-byte `Foo` as an example... if I make 7 sequential calls in a row to `new Foo()`, how many bytes will it *actually* burn through (including overhead)?

For objects that have to be instantiated via `new`, but will persist "forever" (until the next reset), is there any special syntax that tells the compiler/malloc()/whatever, "This object will **never** be destroyed, so there's no need to preserve any information that would otherwise be necessary to release its memory eventually"?

---

Giving this a bit of context, assume `View` is a class with multiple templated subclasses (let's say, `TemperatureView<int, int, int, int>` and `LabelView<int, int, int, const char*>`), and I'm doing something like this:

```
const PROGMEM char* pLABEL = "Foo:";
View* views[] = {
    (new TemperatureView<0,3,0,2>{}),
    (new LabelView<1,4,0,pLABEL>{})
};
```

I'm trying to figure out just how big of a penalty hit (in terms of wasted ram from overhead) I'm taking by rolling it all into one nice, neat combined declaration instead of doing something like:

```
const PROGMEM char* pLABEL = "Foo:";
TemperatureView<0,3,0,2> firstTemp {};
LabelView<1,4,0,pLABEL> firstLabel {};
View* views[] = {
    &firstTemp,
    &firstLabel
};
```

(I originally wanted to put the objects whose addresses were being added to views[] in automatic/stack, but apparently, that's taboo because the compiler thinks the array will outlive the objects whose addresses would otherwise be stored there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make an automatic variable, its lifetime is the lifetime of the function it is inside, so it won't persist forever, unless it is at global scope, or it is declared `static`.

The overhead of using `new` is the size of the object you allocate plus a couple of bytes to keep track of what that bit of memory is used for.

> if I make 7 sequential calls in a row to new Foo(), how many bytes will it actually burn through (including overhead, which appears to be two bytes, see test below)

Seven times the size of the object plus the overhead I mentioned.

Normally you would release that memory with `delete` unless you want it kept forever.

> For objects that have to be instantiated via new, but will persist "forever" (until the next reset), is there any special syntax that tells the compiler/malloc()/whatever, "This object will never be destroyed ...

No. It persists until you call `delete` which there is no compunction to do.

I wrote a test program for my Uno to see what the overhead was, to use `new`.

```c++
#include "memdebug.h"

void showFreeMemory ()
  {
  Serial.print (F("Free memory = "));
  Serial.println (getFreeMemory ());
  } // end of showFreeMemory

typedef struct {char s [20]; } foo;

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();
  showFreeMemory ();   // 1664
  foo * bar = new foo;
  showFreeMemory ();   // 1642
  strcpy (bar->s, "Hello, world");
  Serial.println (bar->s);
  delete bar;
  showFreeMemory ();   // 1664
  }  // end of setup

void loop () { }
```

> I'm trying to figure out just how big of a penalty hit (in terms of wasted ram from overhead)

Two bytes, by the looks, for each allocation.

> (I originally wanted to put the objects whose addresses were being added to views[] in automatic/stack, but apparently, that's taboo because the compiler thinks the array will outlive the objects whose addresses would otherwise be stored there)

I'm not sure what you mean by that, can you give a concrete example?

---

I think you will save more memory by using PROGMEM, which you seem to be doing, a bit.

See my post [here](https://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12615) for ideas about doing that.

---

### Reference

I got memdebug.h (and memdebug.c) from [Andy's workshop - Debugging AVR dynamic memory allocation](https://andybrown.me.uk/wk/2011/01/01/debugging-avr-dynamic-memory-allocation/)

Answer (score 1):

Just as a small complement to the previous answer... The documentation
of the avr-libc has a whole page discussing the workings of `malloc()`.
The section titled [Implementation details](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/malloc.html#malloc_impl) states:

> Dynamic memory allocation requests will be returned with a two-byte
> header prepended that records the size of the allocation. This is
> later used by `free()`. The returned address points just beyond that
> header.

This is consistent Nick Gammon's experimental finding.

Comment: Very good. I was wondering why the overhead was only two bytes, since I thought you might need a length and a pointer, but only storing the length means you can deduce the address of the next chunk. Then when you free up chunks apparently there is a "free list", and they use the (now abandoned) part of memory to record where the next free chunk is. Presumably therefore the minimum amount that gets allocated is two bytes (plus the length).